# This version of query.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I'm running Windows 10 Home. Methods such as running sfc /scannow, dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth, or even copying the files from WinSxS don't even work. Is there any other way for me to retrieve the .exe files so I could execute that ms-dos command?

Comment: What are you trying to run?  DISM and SFC do not make applications compatible - they just fix issues

Comment: I'm trying to run 'query user' to list currently logged in users. About DISM and SFC part, saw a random site that suggests me to do so. I didn't know if it doesn't work that way, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Working fine here. So two things:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run QUERY USER  and then Second, this command may not work on Windows Home. I am using Windows Pro

Comment: It only works on Windows Pro? Ah well, that seems to be the case. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run QUERY USER, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run the command.

Note: This only works on Windows 10 Pro